# Is there a way to create a global object in JavaScript across files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm back again. I had a thought about some code that I would like to split up between multiple files and such. With that, I need an object declared that tracks all stuff, like arrays, counting variables, and that stuff that I need to access and edit across the project.

So, I have a file where I declare all sorts of objects. Let's call this file `Constants.js` in the tree;

```
Main.js
Constants.js
Secondary.js
```

I'm declaring an object in `Constants.js`, then I'm requiring that object in the main file. After that, I need to run a function where that's in `Secondary.js` using the global object and edit it in there. The problem is, if I declare it in the secondary file and edit it, it wouldn't be the same (or updated) in the `Main.js` file, would it?

Ok so, I have my `Constants.js` file laid out like the following -

```js
// Constants.js
exports.Tools = {
  Stack: [],
  Test: "foo",
  Track: 0
  // ...
};
```

In the `Main.js` I'm requiring that object using the following code, and editing what's inside it -

```js
// Main.js
const Constants = require("./Constants.js");
const Tools     = Constants.Tools;

Tools.Stack.push("Some stuff");
```

After that, I'd like to run a function, like so -

```js
// Main.js
require("./Secondary.js").run(Tools);
```

Then after the function has ran, the `Tools` object needs to be updated what the `Secondary.js:run()` did to it. For instance -

```js
// Secondary.js
exports.run = function (Tools) {
  Tools.Test = "bar";
  Tools.Track++;
}
```

And so, I'd like the object in the main file to be updated with the new values that `Secondary.js` did to it.

Is there any way possible for this to happen without using functions in that object or maps? I'd like it to be a normal object.

Thank you very much.
~Q

Comment: Use `global` keyword. Ex: `global.key=value`.

Comment: Modules are only evaluated once, so `require("./Constants.js").Tools` should be the same object instance across imports. You would just need to do the import when/where you need to use it.

Comment: Okay, how does that work, @Vikash Singh?

Comment: Just replace `Tools` with `global.Tools` everywhere. And main.js file would only contain `Tools.Stack.push("Some stuff");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have been doing some digging, and the following example works -

```js
// Constants.js
exports.Tools = {
  Test:  "foo",
  Stack: []
};
```

```js
// Secondary.js
exports.run = function (Tools) {
  Tools.Test = "bar";
  Tools.Stack.push("Second");
}
```

And lastly, the main file that gets ran -

```js
// Main.js
const Constants = require("./Constants.js");
const Tools     = Constants.Tools;
Tools.Stack.push("First");
require("./Secondary.js").run(Tools);
console.log(Tools);

/*
 Outputs:
 {
   Test: "bar";
   Stack: ['First', 'Second']
 }
*/
```

So, the main file's object does get updated when it's passed through the function. It doesn't also matter if you return that object in the Secondary's function.

And also when you do not pass it through a function, it gets ran successfully like so -

```js
// Secondary.js
exports.run = function () {
  const Tools = require("./Constants.js").Tools;
  Tools.Test = "bar";
  Tools.Stack.push("Second");
}
```

I hope I helped anyone who had this question.
~Q

Answer (score 6):

Declare global variable in main file
Main.js

```
 global.Tools = {
  Stack: [],
  Test: "foo",
  Track: 0
  // ...
};
```

In Secondary.js Just use that variables as

```
global.Tools.Stack.push(value)
```

In Node.js global objects are available in all modules, It can be used directly,
No need to import any file.